# Rigorous construction of differential forms?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, differential-forms

Where can I read a rigorous construction of differential forms (k-forms) from first principles?

I have been looking on wikipedia which to get an overview but I would like to study a complete development that covers topics like building the graded ring and how this connects up with derivatives and the Reisz representation theorem.

Comment: Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres and Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak are two classic books that introduce differential forms.

Comment: If you are looking for differential forms on finite-dimensional Euclidean spaces, I think Real Analysis by Rudin is a good reference.

Comment: @AniruddaDeshmukh Do you mean Principles of Mathematical Analysis (aka baby Rudin)? Rudin has another book called Real and Complex Analysis, so it’s not clear which book you’re referring to.

Comment: As a geometer, I find Rudin’s treatment of forms and multivariable analysis among the worst. Spivak and Munkres do everything with tensor product and skew-symmetrizing. For a determinants-only approach, I prefer my own text (and YouTube lectures). :)